# HashMap para pegar um valor

Tags: java

tenho o seguinte código: ele serve para contar quantos segundos eu demoro pra digitar uma frase. Se eu digito BABA o resultado é 10. PORÉM EU QUERIA QUE QUANDO HOUVESSE A JUNÇÃO DA LETRA 'Q' + 'U' ,(COMO NA PALAVRA QUEIJO), ELE CONSIDERASSE UM  VALOR SÓ E NÃO O VALOR DO 'Q' + O VALOR DO 'U'.

OU SEJA, 'Q' NESSE CASO VALE 7 E U VALE 6, EU QUERIA QUE A JUNÇÃO 'QU' VALESSE SOMENTE 7, TEM COMO? TIPO: hashLetras.put("QU", 7);

```
package solucao;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Contagem {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> hashLetras=new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    hashLetras.put("A", 2); 
    hashLetras.put("B", 3);
    hashLetras.put("C", 4);
    hashLetras.put("D", 5);
    hashLetras.put("E", 3);
    hashLetras.put("F", 4);
    hashLetras.put("G", 5);
    hashLetras.put("H", 6);
    hashLetras.put("I", 4);
    hashLetras.put("J", 5);
    hashLetras.put("K", 6);
    hashLetras.put("L", 7);
    hashLetras.put("M", 8);
    hashLetras.put("N", 9);
    hashLetras.put("O", 5);
    hashLetras.put("P", 6);
    hashLetras.put("Q", 7);
    hashLetras.put("R", 8);
    hashLetras.put("S", 9);
    hashLetras.put("T", 10);
    hashLetras.put("U", 6);
    hashLetras.put("V", 7);
    hashLetras.put("W", 8);
    hashLetras.put("X", 9);
    hashLetras.put("Y", 10);
    hashLetras.put("Z", 11);
    hashLetras.put(" ", 7); //ESPACO

    String teste="QUEIJO";

    int count=0;

    for(int i=0; i<teste.length();i++){

        String c = teste.charAt(i)+ "";
        count = count+hashLetras.get(c);
    }

    System.out.println("O tempo foi de: "+count);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, apenas faça um teste lógico com uma exceção, que nesse caso é se o char atual é 'q' e o próximo é 'u' e a posição de 'q' seja até a penúltima posição da String.

Substitua seu for por esse for:

```
for(int i=0; i<teste.length();i++){

    if( i<(teste.length()-1) && teste.charAt(i)=='Q' && teste.charAt(i+1)=='U'){
         count = count+7;
         i++;
    }else{
        String c = teste.charAt(i)+ "";
        count = count+hashLetras.get(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo, deu certo... só fica um delay quando eu coloco: String teste="Q U" (ou seja, 'q' espaço 'u'), ele aparece um valor depois atualiza para outro; colocando o count = count+40 com o número 40 da pra ver direitinho

Comment: Se a resposta lhe ajudou e é a resposta correta poderia confirmar ela?

Comment: resposta corretíssima, muito obrigda

Answer (score 2):

Só para ficar como referência, também dá para fazer como você deu a ideia de meter no hash o `QU` porque o seu `HashMap` é de `String`. Até acaba por ficar mais organizado se tiver várias combinações de duas letras a considerar.

Para isso armazena direto o `QU` com a pontuação pretendida:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hashLetras=new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
hashLetras.put("A", 2);
//... tudo o resto
hashLetras.put("QU", 7);
```

Depois para a contagem precisa primeiro de saber se ainda tem uma letra para a frente. Caso tenha, constrói uma `String` com as duas letras correntes e vê se existe no hash, e só se não existir é que vai utilizar a pontuação apenas de uma letra.

Exemplo:

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0; i<teste.length();i++){
    int pontosDuasLetras = 0;
    if (i < teste.length() - 1){ //se tem pelo menos mais uma letra para a frente
        String duasLetras = "" + teste.charAt(i) + teste.charAt(i + 1);
        if (hashLetras.containsKey(duasLetras)){
            pontosDuasLetras = hashLetras.get(duasLetras);
            i++; //avança logo as duas letras
        }
    }
    count += pontosDuasLetras == 0 ? hashLetras.get("" + teste.charAt(i)) : pontosDuasLetras;
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/sQdCXy)

Nesta solução você consegue adicionar mais pontuações para 2 letras com extrema facilidade, apenas adicionando mais chaves e valores no `HashMap`.

Comment: certíssimo! obrigada